# Getting error "Could not find or load main class weblogic.Admin " while connecting to weblogic server

Tags: middleware, weblogic12c, wlst

I am trying to run below command in shell script but i am getting error like:
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Admin

${SUN_JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -classpath $CLASSPATH weblogic.Admin -url t3://localhost:7001 -username weblogic -password weblogic123 PING

Can anyone comment on it

Comment: weblogic.Admin has been removed since WebLogic 12.2.x

Comment: Yeah. It was removed. Thanks Collin.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known error. Admin has been removed in weblogic 12.2.1.
you may use wlst to try connecting to the Admin server.